# Pagination not working on homepage, On other pages it is working

Tags: pagination

Apologies if this is not the write place to post this question. Please suggest where i can ask such issues as being a not technical user.

My website is www.gahney.com. Pagination is not working on Homepage, although it is working fine on category pages. On home page URL is getting changed as we click on the pagination, but content doesnt change.

PS: I have already trying Permalink reset option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Apy

Comment: I take it you have a custom query on the homepage to change what gets shown? I see there's no code in your question to debug though :(

Answer (score 0):

Add paged as an argument of the query.

```
if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

In your query arguments:

```
'paged' => $paged
```